# Find $,,$ such that $(−, +, −1)=(4, 2, 3)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

I am stuck at this question can someone help me?

I've been trying it all morning but I just cant quite get it going
maybe one of the lads can help

Comment: So you have been trying, good. Can you show us what you have tried? I'm asking because you could be only a small step from finishing it.

Comment: $x = 3, y = -1$ and $z = 4$ does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the equations

$(1) \quad x-y=4$

$(2) \quad x+y=2$

and

$(3) \quad z-1=3.$

Equation $(3)$ gives $z=4.$

$(1)+(2)$ gives you an equation for $x$. Your turn !

Comment: x - y =4
x + y = 2

y = -1   And x = 3 right??

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you need to solve

\begin{align}
x - y = 4, \\
x + y = 2, \\
z - 1 = 3.
\end{align}

The last equation immediately tells you that $z = 4$. Looking at the first equation you can write it as $x = 4 +y$. Plugging this into the second equation you will find
\begin{align}
4 + y + y = 4 + 2y = 2,
\end{align}
or in other words
\begin{align}
2y = -2.
\end{align}
So you know that $y = -1$. For example, looking again at the first equation you get
\begin{align}
x + 1 = 4,
\end{align}
which yields $ x = 3$.

So we found the (unique) solution, namely $x = 3, y = -1$ and $z = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve three equations, being
$$\begin{array}{rcl}x-y&=&4\\x+y&=&2\\z-1&=&3. \end{array}$$
Well, the last one is easy, by adding $1$ to both sides you get $z=4$. To solve $x-y=4$ and $x+y=3$ you rewrite the first equation to $x=4+y$ and then substitute this in the second equation, giving you $$4+y+y=2,$$ which you rewrite to $4+2y=2$, giving you $y=-1$. Then you substitute this in the first equation again to get $x+1=4$ and hence $x=3$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $(x-y,x+y,z-1)=(4,2,3)$

$$x-y=4\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;.....1$$
$$x+y=2\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;.....2$$  $$z-1=3 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;.....3$$

so
from $3$ we can see that $z=3+1\;\;$ so $\;\;z=4$

from add $1$ and $2$ you will get
$$x-y+x+y=4+2$$
$$2x=6$$
$$x=3$$

put $x=3$ in equation $1$ you will get $$3-y=4$$
$$-y=4-3$$

$$y=-1$$

so $x=3$, $y=-1$ and $z=4$